# Not able to straighten line inside a para

Tags: html, css

Hello I am new to css and html.

I had to convert a jade file to html file and I did some css changes to the html file created but I am not able to get the paragraph text in straight line while other text remains as it is.

The html page is as below :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Inliner Build Version 4380b7741bb759d6cb997545f3add21ad48f010b-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    
    <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; height: 100%; width: 100%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="body">
      <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="center">
          <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; background: #405472; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="#405472" class="row header">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
              <td align="center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" valign="top" class="center">
                <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
                  <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="container">
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                      <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top" class="wrapper last">
                        <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="twelve columns">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="center" valign="top" class="center"><span style="color: #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23); display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0;" class="logo"><img src="undefined" alt="undefined" height="undefined" width="undefined"/></span></td>
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top" class="expander"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="align-right">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
              <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;" class="row">
                  <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                    <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top" class="wrapper last">
                      <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="twelve columns">
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                          <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" align="left" valign="top" class="left-text-pad">
                            <h4 style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 12pt; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0 10px;" align="left"><strong>Hi James</strong>,</h4>
                            <p style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 10px 0 30px;" align="left" class="instructions">Library user James has been deleted. Please contact your library administrator for any further queries.</a></p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top" class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need the content "Library user James has been deleted. Please contact your library administrator for any further queries." which is inside a paragraph in a straight line.

The para line is going on the next line instead of staying on the same line.

I tried using width:auto; and display:table-row; but none worked.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please add an image showing your desired result?

Comment: @Hiral please run the code snippet button above.

Comment: it's not clear. I already tried it. please provide some image of what you exactly want.

Comment: Please inspect all your <table> tags. it has fixed width:580px there. Even if you keep it 100%, the line will be cut when there is not enough space to accommodate the whole para in single line.

Comment: @Hiral yeah that solved my problem. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `<nobr>` element or apply this css `style="white-space: nowrap"` around that line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Inliner Build Version 4380b7741bb759d6cb997545f3add21ad48f010b-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    
    <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; height: 100%; width: 100%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="body">
      <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="center">
          <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; background: #405472; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="#405472" class="row header">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
              <td align="center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" valign="top" class="center">
                <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
                  <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="container">
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                      <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top" class="wrapper last">
                        <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="twelve columns">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="center" valign="top" class="center"><span style="color: #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23); display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0;" class="logo"><img src="undefined" alt="undefined" height="undefined" width="undefined"/></span></td>
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top" class="expander"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="align-right">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
              <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;" class="row">
                  <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                    <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top" class="wrapper last">
                      <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" class="twelve columns">
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                          <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" align="left" valign="top" class="left-text-pad">
                            <h4 style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 12pt; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0 10px;" align="left"><strong>Hi James</strong>,</h4>
                            <p style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 10px 0 30px;" align="left" class="instructions"><span style="white-space: nowrap">Library user James has been deleted. Please contact your library administrator for any further queries.</span></a></p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top" class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```